# Does "là où autrefois ..." denote a contrast?

Tags: sens, usage, indications-de-temps, conjonctions

> **Là où autrefois** il lui fallait prendre sa place dans sa propre économie, il s’agit maintenant pour le Québec de prendre sa place dans l’économie mondiale.

I wonder if this expression is considered synonymous with "alors/tandis que"? If so, how would you use it in other examples?

Comment: Oui, *tandis qu'autrefois il lui fallait...* Perhaps for another example: « Là où je ne peux qu'hésiter, debout devant la classe, toi tu n'as pas de difficulté, tu t'exprimes si aisément. »

Comment: @LukeSawczak Tu veux bien faire un pas de plus et préciser la différence, s’il y en a, entre les deux, y compris celle du registre ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically one of many construction French uses where English would use "used to", so yes it's a contrast (something is no longer the case). There's no difference in meaning whatsoever, although *là où* is more elevated in style.